# Github: Download artifact from any repository's Github actions workflow

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I am trying to find a place to upload a binary that has to be executed in all the workflows that we run.

The problem that I am having is finding such a place.

I tried uploading the binary as a release. I am able to download this binary via the REST API but I have to pass in a personal access token to do so.

Is there a way to download a release artifact without passing in a personal access token on an internal repository that is visible to all the users in the organization?

```
                               -----------
                              |           |
                              |  bin.exe  |
                              |           |
                               -----------
                          /         |          \
                         /          |           \
              -----------      ------------      ------------
             |           |    |            |    |            |
             |  Repo 1   |    |  Repo 2    |    |  Repo 3    |
             |           |    |            |    |            |
              -----------      ------------      ------------
```

We have hundreds of repos and we want to pull the release artifact that is hosted in a different repo without passing in a personal access token because adding a personal access token is not feasible on hundreds of repos. We also do not want to host the binary publicly.

If you have been in a similar situation, please let me know on how you resolved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because adding a personal access token is not feasible on hundreds of repos

That means using one key (a [deploy key](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys), associated to the unique repository with the binary, instead of a PAT associated to a user) in order to access said binary.

Using [`gh secret set`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_secret_set), you can add that key to hundred of repository through a script.
Then a common GitHub action can reference that secret when executed in each repository.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. This is not ideal because when it is time to rotate the deploy keys, I will have to run this on all the repos. Also will have to repeat this when a new repository is created. I wish there was a simpler way, like using GITHUB_TOKEN to access internal repos. That way, no one has to manage any secrets and the token is a short lived token that Github handles given that I am trying to access internal repositories within my organization but this is more of a rant. :)

Comment: @Haunted I understand and agree. A GITHUB_TOKEN is liked to a user, instead of your target unique repository). Hence my proposal for a deploy key. Not ideal though.